# Select block using mouse click instead of typing name

Tags: c#, autocad

This is my code which select a particular block in my dwg file according to entered name.
     But i want to select whole page and only want to table of one specific block.
And also the heading part is also give me wrong info i have a four attribute but it print only one on the heading part.Please suggest the solution.

```
 namespace TableCreation
  {
  public class Commands
  {
    // Set up some formatting constants
    // for the table

    private const double colWidth = 15.0;
    private const double rowHeight = 3.0;
    private const double textHeight = 1.0;

    private const CellAlignment cellAlign =
      CellAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    // Helper function to set text height
    // and alignment of specific cells,
    // as well as inserting the text

    static public void SetCellText(Table tb, int row, int col, string value)
    {
        tb.SetAlignment(row, col, cellAlign);
        tb.SetTextHeight(row, col, textHeight);
        tb.SetTextString(row, col, value);
    }

    [CommandMethod("BAT")]
    static public void BlockAttributeTable()
    {
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;


        PromptStringOptions opt = new PromptStringOptions("\nEnter name of block to list: ");
        PromptResult pr = ed.GetString(opts);

        if (pr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            string blockToFind = pr.StringResult.ToUpper();


            Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
            using (tr)
            {
                // Let's check the block exists

                BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(doc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                if (!bt.Has(blockToFind))
                {
                    ed.WriteMessage("\nBlock " + blockToFind + " does not exist.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // And go through looking for
                    // attribute definitions

                    StringCollection colNames = new StringCollection();

                    BlockTableRecord bd = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[blockToFind], OpenMode.ForRead);
                    foreach (ObjectId adId in bd)
                    {
                        DBObject adObj = tr.GetObject(adId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                        // For each attribute definition we find...

                        AttributeDefinition ad = adObj as AttributeDefinition;
                        if (ad != null)
                        {
                            // ... we add its name to the list

                            colNames.Add(ad.Tag);
                        }
                    }
                    if (colNames.Count == 0)
                    {
                        ed.WriteMessage("\nThe block " + blockToFind + " contains no attribute definitions.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Ask the user for the insertion point
                        // and then create the table

                        PromptPointResult ppr;
                        PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");
                        ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";
                        //get the coordinates from user
                        ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
                        if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                            return;
                        Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);
                        //Point3d startPoint1 = startPoint.Subtract();
                        Vector3d disp = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);
                        Vector3d disp2 = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);

                        if (ppr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
                        {
                            Table tb = new Table();
                            tb.TableStyle = db.Tablestyle;
                            tb.NumRows = 1;
                            tb.NumColumns = colNames.Count;
                            tb.SetRowHeight(rowHeight);
                            tb.SetColumnWidth(colWidth);
                            tb.Position = startPoint;

                            // Let's add our column headings

                            for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Count; i++)
                            {
                                SetCellText(tb, 0, i, colNames[i]);
                            }

                            // Now let's search for instances of
                            // our block in the modelspace

                            BlockTableRecord ms = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace], OpenMode.ForRead);

                            int rowNum = 1;
                            foreach (ObjectId objId in ms)
                            {
                                DBObject obj = tr.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                BlockReference br = obj as BlockReference;
                                if (br != null)
                                {
                                    BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(br.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                    using (btr)
                                    {
                                        if (btr.Name.ToUpper() == blockToFind)
                                        {
                                            // We have found one of our blocks,
                                            // so add a row for it in the table

                                            tb.InsertRows(rowNum, rowHeight, 1);

                                            // Assume that the attribute refs
                                            // follow the same order as the
                                            // attribute defs in the block

                                            int attNum = 0;
                                            foreach (ObjectId arId in br.AttributeCollection)
                                            {
                                                DBObject arObj = tr.GetObject(arId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                                AttributeReference ar = arObj as AttributeReference;
                                                if (ar != null)
                                                {
                                                    // Embed or link the values

                                                    string strCell;
                                                    //if (embed)
                                                    //{
                                                    strCell = ar.TextString;
                                                    //}
                                                    //else
                                                    //{
                                                    string strArId = arId.ToString();

                                                    strArId = strArId.Trim(new char[] { '(', ')' });

                                                    SetCellText(tb, rowNum, attNum, strCell);
                                                    ed.WriteMessage(strCell);
                                                }
                                                attNum++;
                                            }
                                            rowNum++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            tb.GenerateLayout();

                            ms.UpgradeOpen();
                            ms.AppendEntity(tb);
                            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(tb, true);
                            tr.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask the user to select a block on screen you can use PromptEntityOptions instead to select a BlockReference. I modified part of your code to include this:

```
[CommandMethod("BAT")]
static public void BlockAttributeTable()
{
  Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  Database db = doc.Database;
  Editor ed = doc.Editor;

  PromptEntityOptions opts = new PromptEntityOptions("\nSelect a block: ");
  opts.SetRejectMessage("Only block references");
  opts.AddAllowedClass(typeof(BlockReference), true);
  PromptEntityResult pr = ed.GetEntity(opts);

  if (pr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
  {
    Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
    using (tr)
    {
      BlockReference blockRef = tr.GetObject(pr.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockReference;

      BlockTableRecord bd = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(blockRef.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead);
      foreach (ObjectId adId in bd)
      {
        // ToDo: here you can handle entities inside the block definition
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me exception "Set reject message exception"

Comment: Use SetRejectMessage first

Comment: still give a fatal error can you olz edit it in my original solution and sent back to me.

Comment: unhandled access violation

Comment: sorry, which line? Are you on debug mode?

Comment: check this tutorial: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=18172834

Comment: Ok.Whenever you free edit that solution and send it to me.